# Raspberry Pi 3 can only play a sound once with VLC

Tags: python, button, audio, raspberry-pi3, vlc

this will be my first post here, hope it will go well!

I am new to both Raspberry Pi3 and Python, but I wanted to give it a try. I have connected my Pi to a button, and when I push it, I want to play a sound. When I run my code, everything looks ok, and when I push the button, VLC plays the wav-file. All good. But... VLC will only play the wav-file once, when I press the button again, only the "Now func1 is done" appears on the screen, but no more sound:(

I need to close and re-run my program to be able to hear the wav again, and only once. How do I get my program to run the wav everytime I push my button without restarting?

Thx!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import vlc

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

player = vlc.MediaPlayer("/home/pi/Desktop/ljud/aliengun.wav")

stime = 1
button = 11

GPIO.setup(button, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def func1():
        player.play()
        print("Now func1 is done")

try:
    while True:
       input_state = GPIO.input(button)
       if input_state != 1:
                func1()
                sleep(stime)

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Try calling `player.play_item_at_index(0)` instead, in case the problem is that VLC attempts to play an item at the end of the playlist.

Comment: Also, instead of using VLC, you could `os.system('aplay /home/pi/Desktop/ljud/aliengun.wav')`. :)